# Extremely New at Laravel, have tried to use Examples, but no go

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I thought this would be a simple usage of has hasMany and belongsTo, but am not getting data for one of my tables, namely title.

I have two tables:

```
scenes  ( movie scenes basically)
------
int scene_id  (can't change to "id".. this is at my company)
string scene_name

int title_id


titles  (movie dvd titles)
------
int title_id    ( same here.. should be id, but it's not )
string title_name
string title_description
```

There are multiple scenes in the "scenes" table, having the same title_id, as you probably guess.

So far, I have:

```
class Title extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'titles';
    protected $primaryKey = "title_id";

    public function scenes() {

        return $this->hasMany('Scene','title_id','title_id');

    }

}

class Scene extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'scenes';
    protected $primaryKey = "scene_id";

    public function title() {

        return $this->belongsTo('Title', 'title_id', 'title_id');
    }
}
```

It looks weird to me that I have to specify title_id for both title() and scenes() member functions.. but that field is what connects each of the titles with their multiple scenes.

The call that I make to get one single scene (assume $scene_id is an int), along with the title information for each scene, is:

```
$scene_info = Scene::find($scene_id)->title();
```

If I do a var_dump on $scene_info, I get a *lot* of Laravel code, which I'm guessing I should not be.
I'm also getting scene information, but the title information is blank.

Just wondering if any of my Laravel coding is way off

Steve

Comment: Show us the first three line of this `lot of Laravel code`, please, will help people to understand what you're getting.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see your comment around the time I posted this question.  I would've posted that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$scene_info = Scene::with('title')->find($scene_id);
```

or you can lazy load the relationship after get the scene:

```
$scene_info = Scene::find($scene_id); 

$scene_info->load('title');
```

Comment: Thanks Anam, that did it (tried the first one only).  Is it normal to get two copies of data:

  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(37) {
and

 ["original":protected]=>
      array(37) {


@Antonio  -  no longer getting the Laravel library embedded in the object. Anam's solution was it

Comment: yes, you will get data including relationships. For example, if your `Scene` model has any other relationship, you can use them later even from view.

Comment: I'm wondering what is the best way to actually retrieve the data.

I'm using the first option above ($scene_info = Scene::with('title')->find($scene_id); ), and when I use either getOriginal() or getAttributes(), I only the data from scenes table, not title.

If I don't use either getXXX, and just try to get at the data manually, the "::protected" part of the element keys are preventing me from getting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what I needed to get my title information:

So it's:

```
$info = Scene::with('title')->find($scene_id); (thanks to Anam)

// to get scene info
$scene_array = $info->getAttributes();

// to get title info
$title_array = $info->getRelations();
```

You'd think, that the call to getRelations() would be unnecessary to get the title info, if you're already specifiying " ('title') " on that first call.

Anyway, thanks again for the assistance from you guys.